# Why would alpha zero not run out of memory

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, montecarlo, monte-carlo-tree-search

After having read through the Deep Mind's Alpha Zero paper, I understood that we are building up a tree and adding a new node to the tree every time we see a new node. For a game like GO (or even CHESS) with such huge state spaces, and such a large training time, we should definitely exceed any practical memory size for such a tree. 
But as I know, the algorithms have been practically implemented. Where is the gap in my understanding?

Comment: You assume that the whole state space is held in memory, and that is not the case.

Comment: Oh okay. Just read a blog on the subject. Realized that the MCTS tree is re-initialized for every game